# How to add QML map to QGraphicscene?

Tags: qt, qml, qgraphicsscene, qquickview, qquickwidget

The app have `QGraphicscene(mpscene)` with `QGraphicsView(mpGraphicsView)` i am trying to add *qml map object* to `QGraphicscene(mpscene)` But map view come separately like popup window. How can i add this map to `QGraphicscene(mpscene)`?

Following are the few methods i tried  as suggested in other posts.

***method1***

```
 PlaneTrack *blr2bgm = new PlaneTrack; //Cpp object set to root context
 QQmlEngine *engine = new QQmlEngine(mpGraphicsView);
 QQuickWidget *view = new QQuickWidget(engine, mpGraphicsView);
 view->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeViewToRootObject);
 view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("blr2bgm",blr2bgm);
 view->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/PlaneTrack.qml")));
 mpScene->addWidget(view);
```

***method2***

```
 PlaneTrack *blr2bgm = new PlaneTrack; //Cpp object set to root context
 QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();
 view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("blr2bgm",blr2bgm);
 view->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/PlaneTrack.qml")));
 view->setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
 QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view);
 container->setMinimumSize(view->size());
 container->setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);
 mpScene->addWidget(container);
```

Comment: please, show your .qml

Comment: @eyllanesc same as planespotter Qt example

Comment: I took plane spotter qt example qml code adding that to scene.

Comment: @eyllanesc is it  loading qml file into graphic scene depends on qml file?

Comment: I have done tests, firstly if you get 2 windows is maybe because the root of the QML is a Window or ApplicationWindow, if so change it to Item, on the other hand I have seen that it is not possible to embed as GraphicScene can not render, for example in a test I made the QML show itself and after a time T is added to the scene it is not rendered correctly.

Comment: @eyllanesc yes you are correct ,window is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  **PlaneTrack.qml** file **window** container was there that i changed to **Item**.
Following code adds qml to graphic scene.

```
    PlaneTrack *blr2bgm = new PlaneTrack; // cpp class object data interact

    QQuickWidget *view = new QQuickWidget();
    view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("blr2bgm",blr2bgm);
    view->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/PlaneTrack.qml")));
    view->setMinimumSize(300, 300);
    view->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);

    mpScene->addWidget(view); // adding to Graphic scene
```